# solr get the total count of a word

Tags: solr

> field1:word1

This will give the count of the documents where word1 exists in field1. I need to get,
1) the total count of word1 of all documents
2) the maximum usage of word1 in a single document in field1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function query `totaltermfreq(field, 'word1')` (or `ttf`) to get the total number of occurrences for `word1` in the index.

Getting the maximum times `word1` occurs in a single field, you can issue a query that retrieves `termfreq(field,'word1')` and sorts `desc` by the same value. The returned set of documents will be where the term occurs the most. Grab the value from the first document (which will be the document where the term occurs most often, and will be the answer for the index).

Comment: Do you know a way to use wildcards in the `termfreq` fq? so you could use `termfreq(text, manage*)` to match "Manager", "Manage" and "Management"?

Comment: @A.O. The comment section is not for asking questions. Please ask a separate question. That being said, you can do that by using a EdgeNGramFilter on the field in question and drop the wildcard.